# Typescript - Extract return type from inner function

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the return type of a function that returns another function?

```js
const creator = (deps: CreatorDependencies) => () => {
  return {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
  };
}
```

I expect to get this

```js
{ foo: number; bar: number; }
```

Comment: What is expected result for above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a use case for TypeScript's [ReturnType<Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility type.

```
type CreatorReturn = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof creator>>
```

`ReturnType<typeof creator>` gives you the type of the function returning your object, and wrapping it in another `ReturnType<>` gives you the object type needed.

Comment: I completely forgot I could nest the ReturnType's, thanks!